counting json objects in output in until
This is a follow-up to the following question:
Count number of json objects in output
I am writing a playbook that will patch our on-premise GitLab runners.  The process I want is:

Pause VM's runner(s)
Make sure no jobs are running (can check with API)
Patch/upgrade
Resume runner(s)

The pause and resume steps are easy and I can do that.  The step I'm having trouble with is the job check.
I can call the GitLab API to get a list of jobs by status for a VM's runners with this:
- name: Wait for No Running Jobs
  uri:
    url: "{{ api_base_url }}/runners/{{ item.id }}/jobs?status=running"
    headers:
      PRIVATE-TOKEN: "{{ PRIVATE_TOKEN }}"
  register: job_list
  with_items: "{{ host_runner_ids.json }}"
  until: job_list.results | json_query('[*].json[*]') | first | length == 0

I keep getting the error:

The error was: Unexpected templating type error occurred on ({% if job_list.results | json_query('[].json[]') | first | length <= 20 %} True {% else %} False {% endif %}): 'NoneType' object is not iterable.

I can take out the until and do a debug task afterwards to make sure the query and everything is correct:
- name: debug job list
  debug:
    msg: "{{ job_list.results | json_query('[*].json[*]') | first | length }}"
  with_items: "{{ host_runner_ids.json }}"

ok: [runner01] => (item={'id': 11226, 'description': 'config01', 'ip_address': None, 'active': True, 'paused': False, 'is_shared': True, 'runner_type': 'instance_type', 'name': 'gitlab-runner', 'online': True, 'status': 'online'}) => {
    "msg": "20"
}
ok: [runner01] => (item={'id': 11227, 'description': 'config02', 'ip_address': None, 'active': True, 'paused': False, 'is_shared': True, 'runner_type': 'instance_type', 'name': 'gitlab-runner', 'online': True, 'status': 'online'}) => {
    "msg": "20"
}
ok: [runner01] => (item={'id': 11228, 'description': 'config03', 'ip_address': None, 'active': True, 'paused': False, 'is_shared': False, 'runner_type': 'group_type', 'name': 'gitlab-runner', 'online': True, 'status': 'online'}) => {
    "msg": "20"
}

So, I know the query works, and I can get the length(aka number of jobs running) for each runner that is hosted on that specific VM server.  I just can't figure out how to make that "Wait for No Running Jobs" to loop and re-check until all the runners have no jobs running(length = 0). In other workds, its out of rotation and the playbook can continue to upgrade it without interruption)
Thanks.
Appending with the json(redacted/trimmed) saved under the job_list variable###
{
    "results": [
      {
        "http request info": "info redacted/trimmed", 
        "json": [
          {
            "id": 1016506,
            "status": "canceled",
            "stage": "scanning",
            "name": "scan_feature_image",
            "ref": "refs/merge-requests/1248/head",
            "tag": false,
            "coverage": null,
            "allow_failure": true,
            "created_at": "2023-12-20T19:10:37.989Z",
            "started_at": "2023-12-20T19:19:00.418Z",
            "finished_at": "2023-12-20T19:19:20.610Z",
            "erased_at": null,
            "duration": 20.191925,
            "queued_duration": 0.953025,
            "user": "info redacted/trimmed",
            "commit": {},
            "pipeline": "info redacted/trimmed" ,
            "project": "info redacted/trimmed"
          },
          {
            "id": 1020404,
            "status": "canceled",
            "stage": "deploy",
            "name": "Elasticsearch_Deploy",
            "ref": "Version-0.5.5",
            "tag": false,
            "coverage": null,
            "allow_failure": false,
            "created_at": "2023-12-28T21:10:28.212Z",
            "started_at": "2023-12-28T21:12:41.546Z",
            "finished_at": "2023-12-28T21:13:04.246Z",
            "erased_at": null,
            "duration": 22.699951,
            "queued_duration": 0.490441,
            "user": "info redacted/trimmed",
            "commit": "info redacted/trimmed",
            "pipeline": "info redacted/trimmed",
            "project": "info redacted/trimmed"
          },
          {
            "id": 1022991,
            "status": "canceled",
            "stage": "scanning",
            "name": "gemnasium-maven-dependency_scanning",
            "ref": "aks-dev",
            "tag": false,
            "coverage": null,
            "allow_failure": true,
            "created_at": "2024-01-03T17:44:15.751Z",
            "started_at": "2024-01-03T17:44:25.035Z",
            "finished_at": "2024-01-03T17:44:52.196Z",
            "erased_at": null,
            "duration": 27.160454,
            "queued_duration": 0.374161,
            "user": "info redacted/trimmed",
            "commit": "info redacted/trimmed",
            "pipeline": "info redacted/trimmed",
            "project": "info redacted/trimmed"
          },
          {
            "id": 1045815,
            "status": "canceled",
            "stage": "scanning",
            "name": "scan_feature_image",
            "ref": "Dev",
            "tag": false,
            "coverage": null,
            "allow_failure": true,
            "created_at": "2024-01-25T23:43:11.020Z",
            "started_at": "2024-01-25T23:43:21.785Z",
            "finished_at": "2024-01-25T23:43:26.569Z",
            "erased_at": null,
            "duration": 4.783896,
            "queued_duration": 1.294567,
            "user": "info redacted/trimmed",
            "commit": "info redacted/trimmed",
            "pipeline": "info redacted/trimmed",
            "project": "info redacted/trimmed"
          },
          {
            "id": 1046169,
            "status": "canceled",
            "stage": "deploy",
            "name": "deploy_feature",
            "ref": "Dev",
            "tag": false,
            "coverage": null,
            "allow_failure": false,
            "created_at": "2024-01-26T16:14:24.659Z",
            "started_at": "2024-01-26T16:14:26.657Z",
            "finished_at": "2024-01-26T16:18:37.569Z",
            "erased_at": null,
            "duration": 250.912905,
            "queued_duration": 1.651202,
            "user": "info redacted/trimmed",
            "commit": "info redacted/trimmed",
            "pipeline": "info redacted/trimmed",
            "project": "info redacted/trimmed"
          }
        ],
        "more misc info": "trimmed for length"
      }
    ]
}


Their json_query was returning a list, yours is not, it does return a single object.

Also mind that there is a length function in JMESPath too: https://jmespath.org/specification.html#length

For a more explanative solution, the best would be to run your loop without the until, debug job_list and [edit] the result of it in your question.

Here is a trimmed version of the job_list information for one of the items in the with_items list.

I added the json_list content(trimmed and redacted of course).  As you can see, json_list.results.json is a list/array of items.
Even ansible can see that the list has 20 items in it.

I think I might have found my issue.  Hopefully it helps others.
When debugging, there is a slight discrepency with how the json results are stored between the original job and the following debug job.
For example, the API call task that gets the list of jobs for a runner gets the results as something like the following:
job_list = {
  misc info: and other stuff
  json: [
    { job1 info },
    { job2 info },
    { etc }
  ]
}

When using a with_items loop, each individual item result will have the same structure above.
However, when I would run a debug task after the looped task, I would see this:
job_list = {
  results: [
    {
      misc info: and other stuff from item1
      json: [
        { job1 info },
        { job2 info },
        { etc }
      ]
    },
    {
      misc info: and other stuff from item2
      json: [
        { job1 info },
        { job2 info },
        { etc }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

So, as you can see, the job_list results from each item is packaged under a results list/array.
Once I switched the until condition to look at the json as a single result:
until: job_list.json | length == 0

Things seem to be working as expected.
So, tip for anyone who sees this:  If you are using a with_X loop such as with_items, and need to add a condition.  If possible, try to get the condition to work with a single item from your list.  In my case, I hard-coded the API call with a single ID.  Then expand to a loop and see how things go.
